# How to check the existence of at least one row within an Oracle APEX collection?

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

Using jQuery alone, how can I check to see if an Oracle APEX Collection has at least one row within it? Obviously I can do this using PL/SQL but I am after a solution that can determine this using jQuery.

Say my APEX_COLLECTION is called 'MY_VALUES' and has a value within C001, after it has been added using `add_member()`.

Comment: Have you checked their [**Js API**?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI29437)

Comment: Does using jQuery to invoke AJAX count? In what situation do you need to do this, there may be another way of thinking about the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Apex collections are held server side. There is no way, as far as I know, to access this information from the client. You will either have to check for the existence of a row during the page load, or you will have to use an Ajax call to find out.